# Где Wine хранит пути к дискам CDEF...XYZ

Tags: linux, archlinux, wine

В папке ~/.wine конфига не нашёл. Может это хранится внутри реестра Шindows?
Как перенести все ранее введённые пути? Их много, не хотелось бы лезть вбивать заново.

Comment: В реестре не нашёл:
https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/2423184

В старой папке вайна ~/.wine/dosdevices старых дисков не нашёл.

Поиск в текстовых конфигах вайна system.reg user.reg userdef.reg  тестового диска с уникальным именем результата не дал.

Comment: Смотрели в *$XDG_OPEN_HOME* (если не ошибаюсь в названии переменной окружения)? Это что-то типа *~/.config*.

Comment: Пришлось просто забить по новой через winecfg.
Как я понял это просто симлинки в ~/.wine/dosdevices. Наверное выход скрипт написать, который их всех создаёт.